# How to escape regex string

Tags: ios, regex, swift, string

I have the following regex string used for determining a valid email address (including special characters e.g. ö, ê, ī, etc):

```
^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$
```

It's tested on https://regex101.com as working regex. I then want to include this string in my code so I have to escape it. I therefore ended up with the following string:

```
^(([^<>()[\\]\\\\.,;:\\s@\\\"]+(\\.[^<>()[\\]\\\\.,;:\\s@\\\"]+)*)|(\\\".+\\\"))@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\])|(([a-zA-Z\\-0-9]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$
```

Now, when I run my code:

```
private static func regexMatch(regex: String, string: String) -> Bool {
    let stringTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", regex)
    return stringTest.evaluateWithObject(string)
}
```

My app crashes with the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching, reason: Can't open pattern U_REGEX_MISSING_CLOSE_BRACKET (string scött.hôdśōn@example.com, pattern ^(([^<>()[]\.,;:\s@\"]+(.[^<>()[]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z-0-9]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$, case 0, canon 0)'

My guess is I am somehow escaping the regex string incorrectly. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: what are you trying to match? This regex seems really strange and there are a lot of misuses of groups and such.

Comment: One thing that I would immediately do is to *break up* that "long-winded regex string" into multiple strings that are concatenated. Spread it out among several indented source-lines to make the arrangement of the total regex "human-evident." ### It sure would be nice to one day encounter a regex library that, upon detecting a syntax-error, *told you* in what column (in this case) the "other bracket" was, but I have yet to find one that extended me such courtesy.  **O_o** ...

Comment: @RNar: Updated the question but its for validating an email address that contains special characters e.g. ö, ê, ī, etc

Comment: If you're escaping you can't have 3 \ in a row, it *have* to be even

Comment: Try to escape always with 2 \ -> "^(([^<>()[\\\]\\. ...." The first \ is for swift.

Comment: Go to regex101, `code generator` select the php option, and get this : `^(([^<>()[\\]\\\\.,;:\\s@\"]+(\\.[^<>()[\\]\\\\.,;:\\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\])|(([a-zA-Z\\-0-9]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$`. Paste it in XCode and escape the string delimiter accordinlgy

Comment: I'm guessing the `\"` is for swift (C-style). Then it shouldn't be escaped.

Comment: Suggestion: break your regex string down into smaller, clearer substrings, then concatenate them together. Makes it much easier to work with :p

Comment: Your regex does not really validate emails with extended characters. See https://regex101.com/r/qN8vG2/1.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, originally I didn't realise that domains can contain special character too. I will try and find a better regex string to cover this.

Comment: If the down voter is around and could give me a reason, maybe I could improve the question. I really think stack overflow should force people to give reasons for down votes as otherwise there is no way for people to improve.

Comment: @Hodson: The downvote is correct. You say your regex is matching emails with extended chars, and I showed you it does not. Now, what you should actually do is to add the regex from your answer to the *question* and then it will be a valid question. The answer you gave yourself is not correct, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

The comments about actually improving your regex should probably be heeded. There were a few things you were not escaping when you should, specifically `]` and escaping when you didnt need to, specifically `.` inside `[]` and `"`. After fixing these in your regex

```
^(([^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+(.[^<>()[\].,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z-0-9]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$
```

And then escaping for special characters, we get

```
"/^(([^<>()[\\].,;:\\s@\"]+(.[^<>()[\\].,;:\\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z-0-9]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/"
```

I suspect the "missing bracket" error was caused by the improper escaping of `]` which prematurely closed some alternator blocks you had. Again, the commentators on your post are correct that the regex itself could definitely be improved

Comment: I seem to get exactly the same error with this regex string too. I may go hunt down a "better" regex string from somewhere online (regex isn't my thing).

Answer (score 0):

I updated my regex string to the following and now it seems to be working.

```
^([^x00-\\\\x7F]|[\\w-\\.])+@((([^x00-\\\\x7F]|)[\\w-])+\\.)+[\\w-]{2,4}$
```

Comment: This is a wrong regex, you do not escape what you must and add too many backslashes where they are not needed.